How to access ENUMs in Google Apps Script?
I can't find any documentation that explains how ENUMs can be utilized in Google Apps Script. For example, I am trying to duplicate the last slide in a presentation. The documentation says:

To call an enum, you call its parent class, name, and property. For example, SlidesApp.SlidePosition.LAST_SLIDE.

However, it doesn't give any syntax for how to actually invoke this.
Assuming that "pres" is the presentation itself, let pres = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();, I have tried:
pres.getSlides()[SlidesApp.SlidePosition.LAST_SLIDE].duplicate();
pres.getSlides(SlidesApp.SlidePosition.LAST_SLIDE).duplicate();
SlidesApp.SlidePosition.LAST_SLIDE.duplicate();
duplicate(SlidesApp.SlidePosition.LAST_SLIDE);
pres.SlidesApp.SlidePosition.LAST_SLIDE.duplicate();
pres.getSlidesById(SlidesApp.SlidePosition.LAST_SLIDE).duplicate();

I just get a bunch of errors. I know this is a simple syntax question, but I can't find any information on Google at all. How do I actually access the last slide using this ENUM?

The Slides Service of Google Apps Script has six classes having a method that use the SlidePosition Enum. The method is setLinkSlide(slidePosition)
The brief description of this method is:

Sets a Link to the given Slide using the relative position of the slide.

The classes are

Class Image
Class Line
Class Shape
Class SheetChart
Class TextStyle
Class WordArt

Reference

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/

To get the last slide you might use
function getLastSlide(){
  return SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides().slice(-1)[0];

}

Example of use of the above function.
This function sets the slide title assuming that the slide layout is one of those having a title shape as the first shape, like the layout "Title and body",
function setTitle(){
    getLastSlide().getShapes()[0].getText().setText('This is the last slide')
}

